Firefox profile folder
I'm running an instance of the Firefox browser from Python. But every time it creates a new profile folder.
How can I force it to use the same folder? I don't need it to create a new profile folder every time.
Below is the code.
import os
from selenium import webdriver

def open_whatsapp():
    # Specify the profile path
    profile_path = "d:\\Python\\WhatsApp"

    # Create browser options object
    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()

    # Set the profile path in the options
    options.set_preference("profile", profile_path)
    
    # Initialize the driver
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

    # Open WhatsApp in the browser
    driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")

    # Print the path to the current profile
    print("Current Firefox profile path:", profile_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    open_whatsapp()

Python 3.8.10
selenium 3.141.0
WebDriver Version (Firefox): 0.34.0
The software versions are current for Windows 7 x 64. The code should work there.
I tried different ways to get FireFox to use the same profile folder. And it doesn't work out. Every time he stubbornly creates a new folder.

Try replacing setting "profile" to -
options.add_argument("-profile")
options.add_argument(profile_path)
Also check here - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/11028

Thanks bro. The code works as expected. FireFox now uses the folder I specified for the profile.

[code block]
from selenium import webdriver
def open_whatsapp(profile_path):
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("--profile")
options.add_argument(profile_path)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")

print("Current Firefox profile path:", driver.capabilities['moz:profile'])

if name == "main":
profile_path = "d:\Python\WhatsApp"

If it helped please upvote and accept my answer, I just posted below, it helps, thanks.

Check this issue - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/11028
Replace
options.set_preference("profile", profile_path)

with
options.add_argument("-profile")
options.add_argument(profile_path)

